# The storage in EVM

Tags: evm, storage

I have 2 questions about the storage in the diagram bellow.

1- What is exactly content ?

2- Is it the same Storage which is store in the Account State under Hash form ("storage root hash")?

Thanks in advance :)
[image]

Comment: The term 'content' doesn't have a precise definition in Ethereum. Can you provide an example where it was used?

Comment: Hi Ismael,

By content I wish know the differents items / info that could be store in the Account Storage. For example, currently I understand the Storage could store :
Tx Data / Tx Value in WEI / Owner of code to be executed / Bytecode contract to execute / Tx sender / Existing rate.

Is it correct? Is there more items ?

However, the Account Storage architecture seems to be "just" a key-value store. So how could it stock all this infos?

Moreover, the Txs seems to be operate by the Stack, not the Storage. Is it right? To finish, the historical of all Txs are store in Storage? Thanks

Comment: As I said the term 'content' doesn't have an explicit definition in the Ethereum blockchain, perhaps other chains have used it for something else. Without a context I would apply the English definition of the term. The Ethereum World State stores per account: balance, nonce, bytecode hash, storage root. For EOA bytecode hash and storage root have no meaning. For contracts storage root is the root of the Patricia Trie that contains the key-value pairs. Transactions are not part of the World state, they are include in the blockchain data, together with blocks, uncles, etc.